# Toggle css of 1 of multiple classes of the same name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have dynamically created divs..

`<div class="container"></div>`

Each div has an input element within it..

```
<div class="container">
   <input type="button" class="container_button" value="toggle" />
</div>
```

My goal is to minimize only the container div of the button clicked..

```
$('.container_button').onclick(function() {
   $('.container').css('height','20px');
});
```

How can I achieve this when multiple divs of the same class exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery object doesn't have `onclick` method, you can use `on` method instead, as you are generating the element dynamically you should also delegate the event.

```
$(document).on('click', '.container_button', function() {
   $(this).parent('.container').css('height','20px');
   //  ^--- clicked element
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to find `.container` relative to the DOM element that was clicked.

```
$('.container_button').click(function () {
   $(this).closest('.container').css('height', '20px');
});
```